# Android Studio Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, resolve

I feel dumb for even having to ask this, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I'm trying to write simple unit tests that test static methods from my Android app and I've already added

```
// Required -- JUnit 4 framework
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
```

To my app build.gradle file, but org.junit.test annotations or anything related to Junit4 will NOT resolve. There is no "Unit Test" build variant either.

[image: Failed]

Can anybody assist me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have not download dependencies:
try run "gradle build"
or sync gradle project if your IDE has this option

Comment: I've tried this by syncing, rebuilding, invalidating cache and restarting, etc. and nothing is working.

Comment: check your project structure; or change "testCompile" to "compile", then rebuild - if it will work, then you should define main and test folders in your project structure;

Comment: Changing testCompile to compile allowed the package to compile but I'm missing things like assertThat, etc. and Unit Tests build variant is still missing. I don't think that should solve anything. Also my file structure is as per the docs.